# Is there a classification of the inner products on $\mathbb{R}^n$ up to isomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, differential-geometry, lie-groups

Let $V := \mathbb{R}^n$, then the inner products on $V$ are in bijection with the set of symmetric positive definite matrices in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$. The bijection is given by sending a matrix $M$ to the inner product given by:
$$\langle v,w\rangle_M := v^tMw\qquad\text{for all $v,w\in V$}$$
If $M,M'$ are two such matrices, then I will say that they give equivalent inner products on $V$ if there is an automorphism $T\in GL(V)$ such that
$$\langle Tv,Tw\rangle_{M'} = \langle v,w\rangle_M$$
This translates into the condition:
$$T^tMT = M$$
which is similar to asking for conjugacy classes of symmetric positive definite matrices, though not quite.

Is it possible to classify the equivalency classes of inner products on $V$?

References would be appreciated as well.

Comment: There is only one equivalence class. See point 3 [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Characterizations).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The classical result that any inner product admits an orthonormal basis exactly says that any two inner products are equivalent. In general, Sylvester's theorem says that over $\mathbb R$ symmetric bilinear forms are classified up to equivalence by rank and signature.